# How to mirror columns on different sheets with one sheet having additional text in front

Tags: excel, vba

I have one sheet (Sheet1) that requires an identifier in front of the value. I have another sheet (Sheet2) that I want to show without the identifier. I would like columns to mirror each other with Sheet1 showing the identifier and Sheet2 not.

I currently have data validation for Sheet2 that allows for multiple values separated by "|". These values are mirroring to Sheet1 but no identifier is being added. Im not sure at what point i should add the identifier. I have tried adding/removing the identifier in the mirroring subs but i keep getting errors. Im not too good at debugging either.

The problem with using formulas is that I need to be able to edit either sheet with the change showing on the other.

```
Sub Sheet2_to_Sheet1(ByVal Target As Range, rng As String, rngTo As String)

Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range
Dim iden As String
iden = "Vehicle"
Set r1 = Range(rng)
Set r2 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range(rngTo)
If Intersect(Target, r1) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
Application.EnableEvents = False
    r2.value = r1.value
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub


Sub Sheet1_to_Sheet2(ByVal Target As Range, rng As String, rngTo As String, Optional identifier As String)

Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range
Set r1 = Range(rng)
Set r2 = Sheets("Sheet2").Range(rngTo)
If Intersect(Target, r1) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
Application.EnableEvents = False
    r2.value = r1.value
Application.EnableEvents = True


End Sub
```

I would like to have for example:

Sheet1, Row 1, Column A = Vehicle.Silverado

Sheet2, Row 1, Column A = Silverado

or

Sheet1, Row 1, Column A = Vehicle.Silverado|Vehicle.Camaro

Sheet2, Row 1, Column A = Silverado|Camaro

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve it without a macro. On Sheet2, apply formula corresponding to Sheet1 cells.

```
=MID(Sheet1!A1,FIND(".",Sheet1!A1)+1,LEN(Sheet1!A1)-1)
```

i have taken the first example (Vehicle.Silverado --> Silverado)

Just copy the formulas to the entire range as required.

Incase you want to achieve it at the click of a button or running a macro, try applying the above formula inside the code.

Hope this helps !

Comment: I dont think formulas will work because i want changes to be reflected regardless of page. Eg. I edit something on sheet1, cell A2 and the change is shown on sheet2, cell A2. It should also work in reverse. If i change something on sheet2, cell A2, the change is shown on sheet1, cell A2.

Answer (score 1):

I've just done it on the same sheet for demonstration purposes but maybe the **SUBSTITUTE** formula will help you out?

[image]

It assumes that you always want to replace the text of `Vehicle.` but maybe that works for you?

Comment: I dont think formulas will work because i want changes to be reflected regardless of page. Eg. I edit something on sheet1, cell A2 and the change is shown on sheet2, cell A2. It should also work in reverse. If i change something on sheet2, cell A2, the change is shown on sheet1, cell A2.